# config postfix with servername apache

Tags: apache-2.2, postfix, return-path

'lo

I would like to configure the retrun-path of postfix using the ServerName parameter of Apache.
Or with an other parameter of Apache.
Is it possible?

Exemple : 
I have /home/toto2/ with /etc/apache2/site-enabled/toto2.conf 
configuration file:

```
DocumentRoot /home/toto2/public_html
ServerName toto2.domaine.com
ServerAdmin retour_toto2@domaine.com
```

I would like that when I send an email from one of the websites (with the php mail function), by default, return-path = apache servername

Comment: Do you mean return path as in the reply-to: field in an email?

Comment: This question is very hard to parse. Could you be clearer with what exactly it is you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to involve postfix in this, when you use the php mail() function (or pear::mail, etc), you can define any and all valid mail headers including the reply-to:, return-path, and so on.

Comment: I am not the developer of these sites.
this is why I want a better solution by modifying the server configuration

Comment: In that case you'll need to call a script from inside postfix to parse headers and insert the ones you need..

Comment: thank I have find: /etc/apache2/site-enabled/xxx.conf
IfModule mod_php5.c
    php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@domain.name"
IfModule